# how to manage a request if an http response is not needed in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, signalr

i have asked some questions about this and not resolved yet. i realized a new and important issue.
i listened the network by using browser and wirehark and saw that if a signalr/connect request is sent, the server does not return an **http response**. it sends some tcp responses and then client sends a signalr/start.

this sample is taken from browser test:

[image: this sample is taken from browser test]

in Jmeter, after sending the signalr/connect request, jmeter waits an http response. and naturally server doesnt send this reesponse. i want to send the signalr/connect request, but not wait for an http response. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - just add some small response timeout (i.e. below 1000 milliseconds), the setting lives at "Advanced" tab:

[image]

The sampler will send the request and fail in 100 milliseconds with [java.net.SocketTimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html): `Read timed out`

If you don't want this failure to appear in the test results as the failure - add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) configured as follows:

[image]

This way JMeter will send the response, disconnect in 100 milliseconds and will mark the sampler as passed.

Comment: it has not solved the problem. if i add the assertion response and a timeout, jmeter sends a RST TCP message and communication will be stopped. i should find another solution from this. jmeter should send signalr/connect request, and shouldnt wait an "http response". does the jmeter make this?

Comment: JMeter does everything given you properly configure it. Have you tried to familiarize with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, especially with **Help others reproduce the problem** chapter? A screenshot showing a HTTP request doesn't tell the full story, I would expect to see body, headers, output of "Follow HTTP/TCP stream" dialogs, etc. I gave you the most straightforward option out of million, the others are use another Thread Group or to [send the request in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/sending-http-and-https-requests-using-groovy-in-jmeter/), etc.

Comment: It will be very big data to share the whole comm. with client and server. i'm trying to ask the same question with different variations but couldnt solve yet. Is the last question not clear yet? there are ten requests that jmeter sends to the server, the four are related with signalr. the first request (negotiate) has responded with http and tcp protocol. the second request (connect) is responded by only tcp protocol. and jmeter waits for an http response. because of any http response are received, jmeter sends a rst tcp message to close the signalr comm. and this is the main problem to me.

Comment: i want to continue as if the http response (to an http request) is received correctly. does jmeter provide this?